# British English: friend vs. mate

Tags: british-english, word-difference

When I was learning English, I just learned the word 'friend'.

Now I begin watching some British TV series, I hear the characters say 'You're my mate', 'He's my mate', 'Cheers mate', etc.

There seems to be some subtle differences between 'friend' and 'mate', but I can't tell. In which situation(s) would 'mate' be more appropriate than 'friend'?

Comment: I don’t agree, precisely, with some parts of them the definitions. I disagree, wholeheartedly, with the spelling errors throughout

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Friend** is the term used in AmE meaning someone with whom you have a bond.

**Mate** is the term used in BrE to refer to a **friend** (in the AmE sense) but may also be a cordial way of referring to **another person** whom you may or may not know.

These two phrases are equivalent in their respective meaning of **someone close**

> We're **friends**
>   We're **mates**

In **AmE**, one's **mate** is usually though of as **one's significant other** or **romantic partner**.

These phrases are equivalent ways of greeting someone:

> **Hello** *(AmE)*
>   **Hey mate** *(BrE)*
>   **G'day mate** *(AusE)*

In BrE, "**Hey mate**!" can be used as a general greeting (usually amoung males), however
"**Hello friend!**" is usually not used in AmE, more often "**Hi there!**" might be used.

Without any context, if a boy and a girl are said to be **friendly**

> In AmE it may be thought they are **friends** or **cordial**
>   In BrE it may be thought they are **more than just friends**, they are **friends with benefits** (AmE)

One would never say they are **matey**.

Other **BrE** words which convey **friendship** are **pal** and **chum**.
**Pal** is more often used in Scotland than **mate** but is interchangeable in meaning.
When two people are **chummy**, they are very close friends.
[**Chums**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTV_Live#Chums) was a parody of the AmE series **Friends**.

Comment: **Friend** is the usual term in British English too! **Mate** is just an informal term, used particularly by younger men. **Pal** and **chum** are both very dated and not in current use.

Answer (score 3):

[Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=mate) notes it this way:

> Slang for "friend" used in New Zealand, Britain, Australia and
>   Tasmania

It is just a cultural difference as there a number of terms that may be used. In Canada, there is buddy, pal, friend, ally and a lot of other terms that could be used to describe a positive relationship with another.

There can also be more than a few other 'mates in English if one wants to add another word to it: Housemate, roommate, and classmate. (Carmate would be one that I haven't ever heard.)

Comment: For some reason, 'mate' is mostly used by men.  It's less common for British women to refer to their friends as mates.